# Is it possible to hack the value of vuex or redux store using devtools?

Tags: redux, vuex

If so, I thought it would be a mistake to put any information related to certification or authorization there.
Is it possible, and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the Redux Store *(or the equivalent Vue implementation)* via DevTools. There's even extensions to make this easier, eg. [Redux DevTools Extension](http://extension.remotedev.io/).

Answer (score 1):

You can edit state directly in the vuex devtool.

[image: edit state]